# Progress bar with Redux createAsyncThunk?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am writing a simple program with React + Redux.
Inside `createAsyncThunk`, I need to send multiple requests to send data chunks.
Now my codes are something like the bellow;

```
export const sendData = createAsyncThunk<
  void,
  {
    id: string;
    data: Uint8Array;
  }
>("files/upload", async (props) => {
  const { uploadId } = await api.init();
  try {
    let i = 0;
    while (props.data.length > i * CHUNK_SIZE) {
      const chunkedData ... // Here I create chunked data from props.data.
      await api.uploadFileChunk({
        uploadId: uploadId,
        data: chunkedData,
      });
      i++;
    }
    await api.complete({
      id: props.id,
      uploadId: uploadId,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    await api.abort({ uploadId: uploadId });
  }
});
```

Currently, I show a loading bar while sending data but it does not tell the progress. I want to improve the program to show a progress bar because it takes a long time if the data is large to send.
How can I manage `progress` with `createAsyncThunk`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be dispatching some sort of action each time that a chunk is loaded.  That way your store is aware of how much has been loaded and can select the progress.  The `createAsyncThunk` function is designed to create three action creators for `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected`.

There is a [second argument](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) after `props` which you have access to in your callback.  That is the `thunkAPI` object which contains your store's `dispatch` method.  You should be able to use this `dispatch` additional actions from inside your main `payloadCreator` callback.

Be careful with `catch`-ing errors here.  I'm not sure but I think this will cause a `fulfilled` response so you would need to use `rejectWithValue`.

It should look something like this (obviously untested)

```
export const sendData = createAsyncThunk<
void,
{
  id: string;
  data: Uint8Array;
}
>(
  "files/upload", 
  async (props, {dispatch, rejectWithValue}) => {
  const { uploadId } = await api.init();
  try {
    let i = 0;
    while (props.data.length > i * CHUNK_SIZE) {
      const chunkedData = // Here I create chunked data from props.data.
      await api.uploadFileChunk({
        uploadId: uploadId,
        data: chunkedData,
      });
      i++;
      dispatch({
        type: "files/uploadProgress",
        percent: //calculate this
      });
    }
    await api.complete({
      id: props.id,
      uploadId: uploadId,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    await api.abort({ uploadId: uploadId });
    rejectWithValue(err);
  }
});
```

If I'm reading your loop correctly, I think you want `i += CHUNK_SIZE` rather than `i++` since you upload a bunch at a time. I'm leaving it up to you to figure out the progress calculations.